# What is the chaining?

Tags: jquery

> When developing a plugin we are recommended to maintain the chainability. Using the **this** keyword maintains the chainability.

So, what is the chaining called in jquery?

Proper demonstration (or description) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what does the article you read this on say?

Comment: Why do you think chaining isn't called chaining?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: In your question you ask `what is the chaining called in jquery?` My comment means exactly what it says: why do you think it isn't called chaining?

Comment: @winterblood seems someone edited my question title so you are asking that>>> enough fair.

Comment: I guess here is some trouble about your obviously *not* mother tongue English, hehe ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called chaining in jQuery.

Plugins should return `this` so that another jQuery method can be called on the same object when the plugin is done.

Example from the jQuery docs (http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#chaining):

```
// Return this in my plugin
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
    return this;
}

// So I can chain another jQuery method
$( "a" ).greenify().addClass( "greenified" );
```

Answer (score 1):

That article is using "chaining" as shorthand for "method chaining." Method chaining is a style of coding that often used in javascript, including in the jquery library.

Here is the basic jist.

Javascript methods can return references to javascript objects. So if you call a method on an object and it returns a reference to an object -- and then you call a method on the (returned) object, then you have a "method chain."

In coding terms, method chains look like this:

```
d3.select("body")
    .append("p")
    .text("New paragraph!");
```

In this case, the select method is called on the d3 object. That select method returns a reference to the body element in the dom (as represented in the d3 library). Then append is called on the body element. Append returns a reference to the p element. Text is called on this p element. The select, append and text methods are said to be "chained" because they are written all together on one line.

I learned about method chaining from [this great post](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/chaining-methods), which is where the examples in my answer come from.

Comment: I read the link until: *JavaScript, like HTML, doesn’t care about whitespace and line breaks.* What about automatic semicolon insertion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#id')
    .css('color', 'red')
    .wrap('<div/>')
    .appendTo(another);
```

When you can chain method calls this way because each method returns object itself - this is called, well, chaining.